# MVC Bundling and cacheing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I'm using System.Web.Optimization with a MVC 4 application, which is hosted on a farm behind some loadbalancers. There are some clients that access this web through a cacheing proxy on their side. We don't have control about their proxies.

MVC bundling is smart, in that it appends a ?v={hash} url parameter behind the bundle script reference, that is unique to the files within the bundle. So, whenever a file in the bundle changes, the hash changes too and the file will be requested again.

The question is: How can I prevent delivery of the bundle, if that hash does not match the current files?

The usual deployment process is:

- take Server 1 out of load balancer
- update Server 1
- test stuff on Server 1
- put Server 1 back in the farm
- Rinse & repeat with all other servers in the farm, one at a time

In the last stept there is a problem:
Say Server 1 and 2 already have been updated, server 3 currently is being updated (and such not in the farm), and server 4 to 8 are not yet updated.

Now there is a chance of approx. 1/4, that Server 1 or 2 answers a request. They both have new scripts and so their hash behind the bundle url is different from the hash that server 4-8 use.

Nevertheless, there is a chance of approx. 3/4, that exactly the next request against this script with the hash for the updated is loadbalanced to one of the not-yet-updated servers. Even though the hashe in the url parameter does not match the older file contents, the bundle still is delivered with the old contents. That is bad for this specific client.

In our worser case scenario, the proxy on the client side now caches the old script under the new url with the new hash, which will lead to this problem being carried over to all other clients behind that cache too.

How can I tell the bundling, to answer requests with a wrong hash with a 404, so that no wrong contents can be cached?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the hash is only used to cache bust on clients.  The server totally ignores this and will just serve the bundle.

The good news is that there is no way for the client to cache the 'wrong' version of the bundle, because we compute the bundle hash using the actual contents of the bundle.  So if your servers still have mixed/stale versions of the files, the hash will change when it is finally updated.

Unfortunately I don't have a good workaround off the top of my head for how you can avoid this situation given that you have a farm with servers is different states.

Comment: The second part is wrong for the explained use case. We have webservers in the farm that are either in the unchanged old state, or the already fully updated state. So when the new servers are in the farm, there is a chance that HTML with a link to a script comes with the NEW hash from an already updated server. That request may be loadbalanced to an not-yet-updated server. This ignores the hash and delivers the old script. With that long-time cache header, all other clients requesting the same new script will be given the wrong (old) script by the proxy. That is clearly a massive problem.

Comment: Got it okay, I understand the issue now